# Jars needed for PowerMock

Tags: android, junit, mockito, powermock

I am already using **Mockito** for unit testing in my android project.
I need to use **PowerMockito** for some functions.
I have downloaded **powermock-mockito-junit** but I'm getting this error:

> Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK:
>       mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker
>       in origin 1 : powermock-mockito-1.6.2-full.jar
>       and origin 2: dexmaker-mockito-1.0.jar

What do I need to do?

Comment: Not an android expert but why on earth would someone need mockito or powermock in the apk?

Comment: Please post your maven/gradle build script and what actions you take to create your APK.  APKs should be distributed to end users, putting in dependencies for a test in there doesn't make much sense.